# How to use streams to JSON stringify large nested objects in Node.js?

Tags: json, node.js, io, stream, jsonstream

I have a large javascript object that I want to convert to JSON and write to a file. I thought I could do this using streams like so

```
  var fs = require('fs');
  var JSONStream = require('JSONStream');
  var st = JSONStream.stringifyObject()
             .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('./output_file.js'))

  st.write(large_object);
```

When I try this I get an error:

```
stream.js:94
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
TypeError: Invalid non-string/buffer chunk
    at validChunk (_stream_writable.js:153:14)
    at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:182:12)
```

So apparently I cant just write an object to this `stringifyObject`. I'm not sure what the next step is. I need to convert the object to a buffer? Run the object through some conversion stream and pipe it to `strinigfyObject`

Answer (score 3):

JSONStream doesn't work that way but since your large object is already loaded into memory there is no point to that.

```
var fs = require('fs-extra')
var file =   '/tmp/this/path/does/not/exist/file.txt'

fs.outputJson(file, {name: 'JP'},   function (err) {
  console.log(err) // => null
});
```

That will write the JSON.

If you want to use JSONStream you could do something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');                          
var jsonStream = require('JSONStream');          

var fl = fs.createWriteStream('dat.json');       

var out = jsonStream.stringifyObject();          
out.pipe(fl);                                    

obj = { test:10, ok: true };                                    
for (key in obj) out.write([key, obj[key]]);                                                                                
out.end();
```

Comment: Your first suggestion leads to `FATAL ERROR: JS Allocation failed - process out of memory`

Comment: I just changed the second one to be exact code for your situation unless large is an array.  Try that.

Comment: I tried the second version however I have a large nested object as one of the `obj[key]` values thats thats whats throwing the memory allocation error. I'd need something similliar that is recursive for child objects

Comment: @kevzettler May I ask how did you solve it with recursion?

Comment: I've created a gist that streams the json with a TransformStream: https://gist.github.com/adrai/713b298fd83da0063910aa9f1674a5ed

Answer (score 1):

Well the question is quite old but still valid for nowadays, I faced same issue but solved it using this **JsonStreamStringify** package.

```
const { JsonStreamStringify } = require("json-stream-stringify");
```

Now,

```
x = new JsonStreamStringify(cursor).pipe(res);
x.on("data", (doc) => {
    res.write(doc);
  });
```

Here you can read your file using fs and then write the above code. **'cursor'** will be pointing to your file.

In this way, you can stream your file in valid JSON Format.

For Docs:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stream-stringify