How to overcome limit length
In V8 (used by Chrome and Node), the maximum string length is 229 - 24 bytes (~1GiB)
I created a parser, but when parsing a large file, oom occurs when the limit is exceeded.
It is a parser that parses all files at once and operates synchronously, so if that limit is exceeded, oom problems seem to occur.
In the v8 engine (used by Chrome and Node), is there any way to use many strings or memory over 1GB? It is okay to use binary rather than string.
I'd like to get some ideas.
The parser I wrote and use

Why do you need it all in memory at once?  Manipulating multi-gigabyte files is really not a task for a browser, is it?

The file converted to json must exist in the browser for the subsequent process to proceed. You need it.

Regardless of whether you chunk it or load it as a stream, the information must exist in the browser.

@k.kh Consider explaining your case. The info may exist in a browser, just not as a single string

"it is a parser that parses all files at once and operates synchronously" - yeah just don't do that for handling inputs that large.

why do you need to parse the whole file at once? it would be better to pull out large chunks, parse that, accumulate the values in a temp object, and continue where you left off. Also i think you can change the mem limits on node with command-line args.

The bottom line is, that is the limit.  You can't change the browser.  Therefore, you need to change your approach.  It's just that easy.

"the maximum length is" -- maximum length of what?

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length
You're not asking this again just to ridicule me knowingly, right?

Just read your files as streams, if they're text files, use a TextDecoderStream. How hard it will be to parse the data as a stream will depend on the format you're parsing (actually tokenizing). For instance csv is super easy: you just need to keep the buffer after the last seen opening comma, but xml or JSON are a lot more complex.

And if your issue is at the stringification to JSON step, then you can compose a Blob made of multiple strings without hitting that limit. This would mean you'd have to use your own serializer though. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61271613/chrome-filereader-api-event-target-result/61316641#61316641 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76438746/converting-huge-json-object-to-blob-by-stringifying-directly-into-an-arraybuff/76439167#76439167
